# Javascript auto scroll div content while still being able to manually scroll

Tags: javascript, html

```
window.setInterval(function() {
var elem = document.getElementById('pullout');
elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}, 0);
```

Im currently using this code to scroll automatically to the bottem. But whenever I want to scroll manualy, I simply can't. Because thats how this code above works. 
Can someone help me with this?

I want the code above + being able to manualy scroll and disable the automatic scroll. But how do I code that?

Comment: You will need to use mouseover & mouseout detection to disable and re-enable the auto scroll.

Comment: have you used any click event for the scrolling? because if you have used above code in `ready` function then it will run after each interval

Comment: When do you want it to scroll to the bottom? When the element first loads? `window.setInterval` will continuously scroll to the bottom, which is why you are seeing this behavior.

Comment: @AJRichardson I want it to scroll to the bottom continuously. Because the div 'pullout' holds a chat system. So there can be chat messages at any given time. And thats what the code does, but I can't scroll manualy now...

Comment: You can attempt to detect when the user tries to scroll, and if this happens, stop the interval; once the user stops trying to scroll, restart the interval.

Comment: It may be more sensible to detect insertion of new chat messages and then trigger the scroll to bottom script, unless the user scrolls to another location in the chat history.

Comment: @SebCooper That makes sense, but how do I code that. Because my Javascript knowledge is not that great.

Comment: Are you coding the entire application? Do you have AJAX calls that get the new chat messages from the server?

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle proof of concept and I will see if I can progress it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You set the interval but it never stop. So whenever you try to scroll, the interval sets it back to the bottom. Given that your interval is 0ms, your code is faster than you when it comes to scroll. to solve the problem, you simply have to remove the `setInterval`. Maybe you are attempting to implement smooth scrolling; if its the case, you are wrong as your code simply automatically scrolls to the bottom.
Simply use:

```
 function funcName(){
   var elem = document.getElementById('pullout');
   elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight; 
  }
```

Comment: You must attach the `funcName' function to an event: something like `document.getElementById('top').onclick = funcName`. If you did that and it did not work, please tell what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of scrolling continuously, I would only scroll when a new chat message is added. Something like this:

```
function scrollToBottom() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('pullout');
    elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}
```

Then, find your code that adds a new chat message, and call `scrollToBottom()` after the message is added.

Answer (score 0):

[`setInterval` repeatedly executes the callback provided](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). An alternative is to use [`requestAnimationFrame` which is a "1 shot" callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame):

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
var elem = document.getElementById('pullout');
elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}, 0);
```